# How to find all references of a particular class's overloaded operator in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

If I have a class that contains an overloaded == operator function, how do I find out where this overloaded operator is being used throughout the code? (Other than placing a break point inside the overloaded == method and seeing if the code ever hits it.) I tried going to the class view in Visual Studio, right clicking on the method, and selecting "Find all references" but it claims there are no references when I know there is at least one that I added.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Temporarily make the operator private and unimplemented. That will catch the uses when you compile.

Comment: Thanks!  I used this to find references to a specific overloaded function in C#.  If I used VS's "Find all references", it found all references too all overloaded functions with the same name but different parameters.

Comment: This is extremely simple but extremely clever. +1 for doing this thing which IDE's seem to fail at doing.

Comment: C++11 allows `=delete` which is now better than this answer, because it also works on free functions. I added an answer with examples.

Answer (score 5):

An update on [Mark B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6917399/457352): mark the function declaration with `=delete`. This will work with all modern versions of Visual Studio, and also works with free functions.

```
class Foo {
    bool operator == (const Foo &rhs) const =delete;
}
bool operator == (const Bar &lhs, const Bar &rhs) = delete;

...
Foo f1, f2;
if(f1 == f2) { // C2280 (…) : attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Answer (score 3):

Comment out the `operator==` declaration in the class and recompile. All the places that try to use the function will generate an error.

Comment: What if there's an inherited `operator==` that matches?

Comment: if the commented operator is declared in some other project, it won't show references from other projects

Answer (score 0):

You can try the add-on [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/default.asp). It really does a lot of enchanced syntax highlighting, but I do not think it highlights overloaded operators.

Visual Studio should show you [overloaded functions](http://wpf.2000things.com/2011/05/05/293-intellisense-will-show-overloaded-methods/) (use the arrows), though AFAIK there is no way to show this for operators.

Comment: Visual Assist doesn't help finding uses of an overloaded operator