# How to find all callers of a c++ function in sublime text 2 or 3?

Tags: c++, sublimetext

Is there any plugin to help finding all callers of any given C++ function in Sublime? Before raising the question here, I have done some search, unfortunately without any luck :(.

Here is an example. Assume I have a source file looks like below:

```
class A
{
    public void init()
    {
        cout<<"init in class A.";
    }
};

class B
{
    public void init()
    {
        cout<<"init in class B.";
    }
};

class C
{
    public void call()
    {
        A a;
        a.init();
    }
};

class D
{
    public void call()
    {
        B b;
        b.init();
    }
};
```

When I search for `class A`'s `init()` method, I want to find all the callers and the correct answer should only include `class C`'s call function, however, cscope plugin within sublime will give me both `class D` and `class C`'s call functions, my guess is cscope failed to differentiate the `class B`'s `init()` function and `class A`'s `init()` function and somehow think that they are the same function and thus return the callers for both of them?

Comment: Install the cscope plugin

Comment: I'm not a C++ guy, but I know Sublime quite well. Can you [edit] your question with some example code showing what you're searching for, with some correct, desired results, as well as some incorrect results that you'd like to avoid? Sublime's search capabilities are quite powerful, so I'm sure we can figure something out.

Comment: @MattDMo, here is an example. Assume i have 4 files in the projects, A, B, C and D, where A defines classA like below:

Comment: @user3831790 thanks for the examples. Wouldn't the classes be called `class A` and `class B` so you could then define an instance of `A` with `A a;`?

Comment: yes, you are right :)

Answer (score 4):

Based on an excellent, general-purpose [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6917399/391161) that I used earlier today, which transcends editors and platforms.

Just comment out the function and look at all the lines which have compiler errors.

Comment: Actually, commenting out the function *declaration* should be enough in C++ (but not in C).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I have written my answer to be general enough to cover the case where the function is defined in a header file, but that is a fair point.

Comment: … Except for calls that still match a different overload.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, Very good point, but the OP did not specify whether he is trying to find *all overloads of a particular function name*, or callers of a *unique function with a unique signature*.

Comment: @Praetorian, tried with cscope, but seems like it does not work as expected, e.g, if i'm finding a function with a common name, like start(), the search results will contains all the callers of all the start() methods, rather than the all the callers of the EXACT start() that i'm searching for. I noticed this because i compared the search results with the one i got from source insight3, which gives me the correct answers.

Comment: @merlin2011, if this is the only way to achieve my goal, then i think i still cannot leave source insight(which i'm currently using) as for now, which is a pity...

Comment: @user3831790 As you might guess I am not a sublime user. Stay on and check for some real sublime user to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Sublime Text package supporting CTags which may be what you need [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags).

If you have [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) installed, you can install the CTags package directly.

Comment: No, CTags cannot do "find references"

Answer (score 0):

I use CscopeSublime package which provides lookup symbol functionality. Please look at https://github.com/ameyp/CscopeSublime.

Comment: Links tend to change or go missing, could you explain some of the contents or quote it here?